# How do I show the classification tree and confusion matrix on both train and test set

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How do I show the classification tree and confusion matrix on both train and test set

For discussion purposes, cause it hard to do this alone!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm_train = confusion_matrix(y_train, y_train_pred)
cm_test = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_test_pred)
```

Then you can just print `cm_train` and `cm_test`. An alternative is to 'plot' the confusion matrix. In this case, you can refer to the following document: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html

In the case of Decision Trees, you will need graphviz, joblib, os, StringIO and pydotplus. You can do the following:

```
import joblib, os
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
import pydotplus

outputPath = 'treeModel.joblib'
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
joblib.dump(clf, outputPath)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
graphviz_path = 'C:/Users/../bin/graphviz' #this should be your graphviz path
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + graphviz_path
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data,filled=True, rounded=True,special_characters=True, feature_names=features)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()).write_png('Decision_Tree.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sb.set()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

dectree = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 4)
dectree.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_train_pred = dectree.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = dectree.predict(X_test)

print("Classification Acc \t Train:", dectree.score(X_train, y_train))
print("Classification Acc \t Test:", dectree.score(X_test, y_test))

f, axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(12,4))
sb.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y_train, y_train_pred),
          annot = True, fmt=".0f", annot_kws={"size":18}, ax=axes[0])
sb.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_test_pred),
          annot = True, fmt=".0f", annot_kws={"size":18}, ax=axes[1])
```